# How to use if in comparing 2 strings in ADB shell

Tags: shell, adb

How to use if in comparing 2 strings in ADB shell,
I am trying to use :

```
if ["a" = "a"];
then
fi
```

this gives an error [: not found

I tried all the varients of if , got the same error,

even just

```
if [];
then
fi
```

is also giving the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put spaces inside the brackets, like this:

```
if [ "a" = "a" ]
```

Comment: Does that mean my answer worked for you?  I'm pretty sure it will work, but am not sure how to interpret your comment.  Also note that you need to put some command after the `then`, even if it's just `echo` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html, adb (Android Debug Bridge) uses the `ash` shell.

I don't have `adb`, but I do have `ash` on my Ubuntu system.  On that system, the following works:

```
if [ "a" = "a" ]
then
    echo ok
fi
```

Try that *exact* code in your adb shell, including all the spacing.  In particular the spaces around the `[` and preceding the `]` are mandatory.

Note that the semicolon after the `]` is not required; it's probably ok, but delete it just to be sure.  (You said you "tried all the similar stuff".  Don't try "similar stuff"; try this.)

Are you sure you're in the shell (`adb shell`) and not in `adb` itself?  (I don't know whether `adb` has an interactive mode, so that might not make sense.)